# Excel: how to concatenate a number and a string

Tags: vba, concatenation

I have to write a position in the cell in the form of "1." with a macro. Whatever way I have tried to concatenate a number and a dot, it always only writes a number. If I add a strin before the number, the output is written properly. If I add another character after the dot, it also writes the outcome properly. Examples:

```
Sub concat()
Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim position, dot As String
Dim checkRow1 As Integer
Set currentSht = Sheets("Predtekmovanje")
position = "2"
dot = ".h"
currentSht.Range("AY8").Value = CStr(position) & dot
End Sub
```

If somebody finds a clever way on how to make the output in the form of 2. in the cell, I would really appresciate it.

Comment: Are you sure that the actual data of the cell is wrong? It sounds like the issue is that Excel formats the value as a number.

Answer (score 1):

First change the number format to `Text` and then add the value.

```
currentSht.Range("AY8").NumberFormat="@"
currentSht.Range("AY8").Value="1."
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a custom number format? Like this:

```
With Sheet1.Range("A2")
    .NumberFormat = "#."
    .Value = position
End With
```